# Why am I getting duplicate location co-ordinates from the instagram API?

Tags: location, instagram-api

I am currently working on an app that pulls in Instagram photos using a location search and the Instagram API, and then plots the location through Google Maps API.

I've collected hundreds since I set up the feed, but most of them are being reported as being at the same location (in terms of co-ordinates). I can't see any reason for this (i.e. I don't believe that all the photos were taken from this location), so I'm wondering if there is something I don't know about how the location is determined.

I am assuming it is based on the phone GPS and that if location services is turned off for the Instagram app, then I won't get these photos in my feed (the location would be null).

See an example in this link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/axXCP.jpg

EDIT: I should add that I have looked at the photos attached to the duplicate location, and they were not taken from this location e.g. most are of the Eiffel tower, which is not viewable from this location :-)

EDIT2: I also am having this problem with the Twitter data I am pulling from this location, with most of the "locations" being recorded as the same duplicate co-ordinate as for the Instagram data.

Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

When someone adds a location to their photo in Instagram, they do a search and Instagram returns a list of nearby locations that match their search. In your case, users could be selecting a location that looks right, but might have an odd lat/lng.

You might be getting the lat/lng of that location and not of exactly where the picture was taken.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I've came across this related post as well http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44608/google-maps-location-history-is-showing-an-incorrect-location which also helps explain what might be going on.

Comment: Hi again Bill. I'm not sure all the photos are tagged manually by the user when they upload (or that is how Instagram is getting the location). This is a view of the location data without clustering http://i.stack.imgur.com/anaep.png, and I can't imagine users finding specific landmarks or options to select for some of these locations :-)